# How to activate the insertion of ByVal keyword by default in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In **Visual Studio 2015**, which is the option that I should enable/disable to activate the auto-generation of `ByVal` keyword for **VB.Net**?

I've tried to toggle the "**Pretty listing (reformatting) of code**" option, but it does not take effect.

Maybe is there an alternative solution via 3rd party extension for **Visual Studio**?

Comment: ByVal is the default for method arguments, it is not required.

Comment: It is required if you want to format the code following good practices.

Comment: I don't follow you. The format of code is just fine without adding unnecessary keywords. I see you edited your comment to refer to good programming practices. Can you explain why you think adding unnecessary `ByVal` keywords is a good practice?

Comment: Is only unnecessary for the compiler and also for lazy developers, but is part of the language then ...its necessary for me, to format the code. thanks for comment.

Comment: [OFFTOPIC] I remember those days when StackOverflow had more users that tried to bring solutions in answers, instead of discussions with no reason and phantom downvoters without criteria. [/OFFTOPIC]

Comment: I agree, it could very well be a code convention followed by a team. No need to question it imo.

Comment: Granted this is a little older, methinks nothing has changed (at least from a Settings standpoint):  http://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2011/03/15/vs-2010-sp1-changing-quot-byval-quot-vb-net-code-editor-experience/

Comment: @NoAlias Thanks for the url, too bad to know the developers decission and response to 'Carlos Quintero' ...its irrational and ridiculous to ignore the need of a customizable option in the IDE options for the end-user for things exactly like this one, how much will cost to do that little thingy, VS Dev. Team? (nothing, they did it in the past), anyways the article is 4 years old, I wonder something has changed in this time... if not then maybe could exists an extension that implements the "Auto-ByVal" behavior when typing parameters?, who knows...  thanks again.

Comment: Agreed, I prefer it being the default too.  I understand that they want to make C#/VB.Net more uniform and that it shrinks the code base, but it seems like a perfect thing to make configurable for us "old school" guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour was changed in Visual Studio 2010 service pack 1.

Carlos Quintero [writes in his blog](http://blogs.msmvps.com/carlosq/2011/03/15/vs-2010-sp1-changing-quot-byval-quot-vb-net-code-editor-experience/):

> "I e-mailed the program managers who changed this behavior, which in
>   turn introduced me the developer, and they confirmed that there is no
>   setting (and no plans) to get the old behavior in the VB.NET code
>   editor."

So, the only possible way to get the behaviour back for now seems to be to install Visual Studio 2010 and no service packs. That might not be a reasonable solution for most...

The main reason that the `ByVal` keyword was added automatically in the first place seems to be that the default way of passing parameters in VB 6 was `ByRef`. The default supposedly had to change for VB to make a reasonable transition into .NET, but it would confuse VB 6 programmers, so the IDE automatically made it specific.

Nowadays there is no longer a need to make it specific to avoid confusion for VB 6 programmers. If you transition from VB 6 to VB 14 you should expect dramatic changes.